# Not sufficient brightness from Constant Current LED drive to 3W mini LED, with Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino, pwm

Now, after read my 6 thread tip, no solution clearly given, so I go ahead to  my problem.

When I  power on my 4 LEDs gave      fast full flash brightness for 3-4 seconds. That's a   sign that    all LEDs are ok.  After this the pattern starting   it goes to approx. 20 % brightness. In the    product description, this CC DRIVER LED was a dedicated PWM using with Arduino. As diagram view, I'm using 2 parts of Li-Ion battery 18650/3400 mAh as power source, step up converter prevent 12-14 volt. I was also try switch mode power supplies, 12 V 30A. This         changed the brightness to approx. 30 %.

To find out where this current as 40 mA from Arduino output goes Is measured the output pin voltage. My multi meters has 3.9mV as "noise" voltage when not connected      . I can see I measured  peak voltage from Arduino PWM output to 200mV! Normal this pulse as high/ON are 5V max load 400 mA. As I understand this PWM unit dedicated for use together with Arduino, which makes  no sense to me what are wrong to my diagram. It sounds like this PWM give Nano output goes overload?

Go to this URL and find all  device parts eg. other info in the Word-doc.  https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DD2C186E5334F02C!368166&authkey=!AHIQO10jd5sa-xk&ithint=file%2cdocx

Appreciated volunteers with help and tips!

[image: Arduino Nano CC DRIVE LED diagram]

Comment: what sort of fuse do you have?

Comment: Please insert the document into the body of the post.  The problem with links is that they die and the question loses context.  It will add to the length of the question, but length is not a problem.

Comment: I'm not going to download some random, possibly malicious, document. Particularly not when it's a Word doc. Put all the relevant information in your post, and link to datasheets.

Answer (score 2):

You are driving 2.8A (4x700ma) constant current LED drivers from a 2 amp power supply  Try bypassing your converter and use your battery fully charged to see if it will run your LED's fine.  Make sure to keep a common ground with your nano.

Comment: well spotted, and I thought the fuse looked suspicious!

Comment: Due to restriction of only 2 URL, as new in this forum, I need to post an external URL for all my 5 different URL address. Sorry for that, but understand why. Of course, I could post spam/malware to my Microsoft OneDrive server, or? End of this information, why.

Comment: So  to question: my fuse? suspicion= A standard glass fuse.

Comment: 1. My power source; in diagram, yes it's 2X 3400mA, 7,6 volt. But later in my text infomation, a switch mode 30A PS was tryed. Same result, but this test was BEFORE this buck-Step up converter. 2. And I'm not try to drive 2.8 A current load throughout this buck, it's only 700mA CC at once, if you are see my code. If you don't believe I'm not a shooter of " random, possibly malicious, document", then quit your interesting for help me. And, my links will not did not die, I'm the owner of it.

Comment: Everything you are trying to do should be tolerant of your batteries voltage (at full charge) throw a fat capacitor for your arduino's VCC and ground and see what happens.  One thing that might be happening is your batteries under loading dropping to lower voltages causing some issues, do you have more cells to throw in line?